# php styleswitcher cookies not set in wordpress. why?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

*Update a day later: Cookies are now being set.  I try to show the changes I needed to make with the edits in the code quoted below.  There's still a problem.  Now it's not applying the non-default stylesheets! The browser can find them, but not the switcher....*

(original question:)
I'm using Rob Ballou's v.2 Styleswitcher (robballou.com/switcher/v2/tutorial.php), in a WP3 blog (site is [here](http://molvray.com/govforum/)). I've altered the stylesheet urls, so that WP knows where to find them:

from:
`$ss->addStyle("default", "style.css", "", "", true);`

to

```
$my_url = get_bloginfo('template_url');

$ss->addStyle("default", $my_url . '/style.css', "", "", true);
```

Judging by the document source, the style sheets are being found.  So that's not the problem.  However, the cookie just is not getting set.  If I run the exact same scripts on a web page (eg molvray.com/testing/ss-example.php), it works, and when I check the cookies, cwStyle has been set.  But as soon as it's in WP, no luck.

I'm guessing the problem is this line: `$ss->cookieDomain = ".". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];` in switcher.php.  I saw a post that suggested using HTTP_REFERRER instead, but that doesn't help. I've included switcher.php below. I haven't touched Styleswitcher.php itself.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I'm going nuts here!

Please be as dumbed-down as you can, so that I have a snowball's chance of following.  I'm pretty useless at programming.

*New: most of switcher.php is included in header.php instead of as a separate file.*

in header.php:

```
<?php
```

<strike>require_once("Styleswitcher.php");

$ss = new Styleswitcher('/switcher/v2/');</strike>

```
if(!isset($reqPath)){ $reqPath = ""; }
require_once($reqPath ."Styleswitcher.php");
$my_url = get_bloginfo('template_url');
$ss = new Styleswitcher();

$ss->addStyle("default", $my_url . '/style.css', "", "", true);
$ss->addStyle("lowgraphics", $my_url . '/handheld.css');
$ss->addStyle("highcontrast", $my_url . '/highcontrast.css');

$ss->createSet("style");
$ss->addStyleToSet("style", "default", true);
$ss->addStyleToSet("style", "lowgraphics");
$ss->addStyleToSet("style", "highcontrast");

$ss->cookieDomain = ".". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$ss->cookieName = "cwStyle";
```

<strike>$ss->start();</strike>

```
$ss->printStyles();
    ?>
```

the actual switcher.php is then just:

```
<?php
if(!isset($reqPath)){ $reqPath = $my_url; }
require_once("Styleswitcher.php");
$ss = new Styleswitcher('/switcher/v2/');
$ss->cookieDomain = ".". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$ss->cookieName = "cwStyle";
$ss->start();
?>
```

form as used in the header.php of wordpress has "<_?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/switcher.php" instead of just "switcher.php"

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/switcher.php" method="post">
```

<strike><_input type="hidden" name="referer" id="referer" value="" /></strike>

```
    <input type="hidden" name="inputStyle2" id="inputStyle2" value="style" />        
    <li><input type="submit" name="style" id="default" value="Default" <?php $ss->printSetInputChecked("style", "default"); ?>/></li>    
    <li><input type="submit" name="style" id="lowgraphics" value="Mobile" <?php $ss->printSetInputChecked("style", "lowgraphics"); ?>/></li>
    <li><input type="submit" name="style" id="highcontrast" value="High&nbsp;Contrast" <?php $ss->printSetInputChecked("style", "highcontrast"); ?>/> </li>
    </form>
```

The crucial bit, I think, was adding the php bloginfo('template_url') path to switcher.php in the form element.  Now on to figuring out why it doesn't go to anything but the default style.

Comment: Where are you running the main chunk of the code? Inside a template file? If so which file? Inside a plugin?

Comment: The main code is in Styleswitcher.php, which is unchanged from the download.  switcher.php calls that, and contains the settings you might need to change. Both are in the blog dir for template files.  What I changed in switcher.php is the "myurl" line and the path to the style files.

Comment: Switcher.php is called from within the template file, header.php

Comment: TheDeadMedic: I've managed to get it setting cookies (although I don't understand why) and I've updated my original question.  The only style it'll apply, though, is the default, so I'm not there yet.  :(

Answer (score 0):

(continued response to The Dead Medic.  I don't have the hang of the system here yet.)

I've also been looking around some more, and found something about a problem with WP registering global variables.  http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-blog-headerphp-killing-sessions

I tried making a php.ini file in the blog root dir, with "register_globals Off" as suggested toward the end of that thread, but that didn't seem to do anything.

There's also this link, h_ttp://www.scratch99.com/2008/09/setting-cookies-in-wordpress-trap-for-beginners/ which talks about giving setcookie an explicit path, but I'm not clear how and where that would fit into my switcher.php above.

(To answer your last question: no, this isn't a plugin.  WP is pathetic on styleswitchers, hence this odyssey :S )

Comment: I've now also had a chance to try the suggestion about turning off globals in wp_settings.php, but, as far as I can tell, in wp 3.01 it's already off. ("wp_unregister_GLOBALS();") There was also a suggestion to add "session_start();" to the top of wp_config.php (without quotes of course) but that, too, did nothing. I've been making sure to completely reload the web site between changes, but I haven't shut down the browser, if that could be an issue. I've also tried changing my cookieDomain in switcher.php to "$ss->cookieDomain = "/", ".molvray.com"; but no luck there yet either. :(